# How to get tab visibilities for standard tab?

Tags: metadata-api

Trying to put a permission set in source control that grants access to the Ideas tab.  I've been able to download the tab visibility by adding the Idea as a custom object to my package.xml, but that also downloads all the field and object permissions as well.  Is there anyway to just grab the permissions for a standard tab?

In theory it would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Idea</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Display_Ideas</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>26.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard tabs aren't exposed as top-level component in the metadata api. You can get at the visibility via the Profile, but you'd obviously need to retrieve all profiles to get the full picture.

Comment: Still the case as of Spring '17 :-(
Having a permission set with a standard tab visibility requires post-deployment step.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm?search_text=tabvisibility
```ProfileTabVisibility represents the visibility of tabs for this profile. For version 17.0 and later, ProfileTabVisibility supports visibility of tabs for standard objects. The manifest file must include the standard object corresponding to a standard tab to retrieve the tab visibility in a profile```

Answer (score 2):

To pull *just* the tab visibilites, not sure there is a way.
However, in order to set standard object tab visibilities in a profile,

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>standard-StandardObjectApiName</tab>
    <visibility>[DefaultOn|DefaultOff|Hidden]</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

should do the trick. Example:

```
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>standard-Pricebook2</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
```

Solved my own comment-post 6 years later!

Comment: Another quick hack to find the exact object api name is to go to Profile(enahnced view) >> Objects >> Tab (such as "Orchestration Runs") >> Observe URL having Object API Name >> In this case "FlowOrchestrationInstance"